# Selecting rows which not alread in another table

Tags: mysql

There are three tables in my database, called `profiles`, `profile_groups` & `profile_group_members`.

`profiles` contains basic details about employess (user_id,firstname, lastname, email)
 `profile_groups`contains profile groups such as executives, clerical_staff, support_staff (group_id, group_name). 
`profile_group_members`contains members in each groups.(id, group_id, user_id).

Now I want to list users who are not already in a specific group.

 For an example : I want to list users who are not already in group_id 2

I found various articles from Stackoverflow but any of them not worked for me. 
Please help me to write the code.

Edit : 
@Paul's code works!!

Comment: pseudo code: `select * from profile p where not exists(select * from profile_group_members pg where pg.user_id = p.user_id and pg.group_id = 2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows which are not present in other table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - It works.! Thank you+

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - How do I edit the query if I want to merge the following query with your one?
select * from profiles where firstname = '$query'

Comment: `where firstname = '$query' and not exists(...)`. Also have a look at [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to make your code more secure.